# jgraph layout does not work

Tags: java, graph, graph-visualization

I use jgraph ver. 5.14.0.0. ( http://www.jgraph.com )

When I try to apply layout to a jgraph, but for some weird reason it does not work.

```
public static void layout(JGraph graph) {
    JGraphFacade facade = new JGraphFacade(graph);
    JGraphSimpleLayout lay = new JGraphSimpleLayout(JGraphSimpleLayout.TYPE_RANDOM, 100, 100);
    lay.run(facade);
}
```

I run this code to layout a graph, but cells does not move.

I have not found tag for jgraph library.

Answer (score 2):

Based on http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossas/projects/mc-tools/grapher/trunk/src/main/java/org/jboss/mctools/grapher/layout/ReflectionGraphLayout.java, you are only missing a couple lines:

```
final JGraphSimpleLayout graphLayout =
    new JGraphSimpleLayout(JGraphSimpleLayout.TYPE_RANDOM, 100, 100);
final JGraphFacade graphFacade = new JGraphFacade(jgraph);
graphLayout.run(graphFacade);
final Map nestedMap = graphFacade.createNestedMap(true, true);
jgraph.getGraphLayoutCache().edit(nestedMap);
```