# Formatting a JGraph graph using com.jgraph.layout - refreshing the display

Tags: java, swing, awt, graph-visualization, jgrapht

I'm writing my very first program in Java that actually does UI, so please bear with me if the answer to this is obvious.

I'm using JGraph 5 (5.14) to visualize a graph created by JGrapht (0.8.3).

I can create the graph with JGrapht just fine, and I believe it gets converted to JGraph OK using org.jgrapht.ext.JGraphModelAdapter.  The problem is, when the result is displayed in a window (I'm using a panel in a JApplet) all the vertices are displayed on top of another.

Someone else had this problem ([JGraph Layout Does Not Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496114/jgraph-layout-does-not-work)) and I tried the solution presented there, but then only two nodes are displayed.  Basically, I just want the graph displayed in some way where the nodes are separate from each other.

Some code is worth a thousand words, so here is what I currently have, which only displays two nodes (there are 219 in the graph):

```
class ourGraphVisualizer extends JApplet
{

private static final Color DEFAULT_BG_COLOR = Color.decode("#FAFBFF");
private static final Dimension DEFAULT_SIZE = new Dimension(1280, 1024);

// this init overrides the JApplet.init().  Our class here extends JApplet so we can do the visualization
public void init(ListenableDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> theGraph)
{
    JGraphModelAdapter<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> jgAdapter;

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(DEFAULT_SIZE);

    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    scrollpane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollpane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    this.getContentPane().add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.add(this);
    frame.setTitle("Call Graph, " + theGraph.vertexSet().size() + "nodes");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setPreferredSize(DEFAULT_SIZE);

    jgAdapter = new JGraphModelAdapter<String, DefaultWeightedEdge>(theGraph);

    JGraph jgraph = new JGraph(jgAdapter);

    panel.add(jgraph);
    resize(DEFAULT_SIZE);

    // Let's see if we can lay it out
    JGraphFacade jgf = new JGraphFacade(jgraph);
    JGraphFastOrganicLayout layoutifier = new JGraphFastOrganicLayout();
    layoutifier.run(jgf);
    System.out.println("Layout complete");

    final Map nestedMap = jgf.createNestedMap(true, true);
    jgraph.getGraphLayoutCache().edit(nestedMap);

    jgraph.getGraphLayoutCache().update();
    jgraph.refresh();

    frame.setVisible(true);
    panel.setVisible(true);
    scrollpane.setVisible(true);
}
```

Any constructive suggestions/help/inspiration will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks...

-Eric

Comment: Hi user1055696... No, I never got it worked, so I punted.  using JGraphT, I exported the graph into GraphML and then used Perfuse to read the GraphML and visualize it.  It was a little tricky, but it worked!

Answer (score 2):

If u want to avoid overlapping of your Vertex just try different graph Layout i havegiven some here this one for hierarchical layout and call run method of this

```
final  JGraphHierarchicalLayout hir = new JGraphHierarchicalLayout();
final JGraphFacade graphFacade = new JGraphFacade(jgraph);      
hir.run(graphFacade);
        final Map nestedMap = graphFacade.createNestedMap(true, true);
        jgraph.getGraphLayoutCache().edit(nestedMap);
```

Answer (score -1):

It'll be a much better idea to create two JPanels and add your graphs individually to the JPanels and the JPanels to the the JFrame using an appropriate layout manager

Comment: Thanks, verdant, but could you flesh out the details a bit?  In particular, I only have one graph... do I need two JPanels?  Also, how do I "... add graphs to the JPanel using an appropriate layout manager?"  How does a layout manager interact with the JPanel?  Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: It seems the 'layout' the OP refers to is not a 'layout manager' as often discussed, but a concept specific to the objects in the graph.

Comment: Truly, Andrew!  The line: JGraphFastOrganicLayout layoutifier = new JGraphFastOrganicLayout();
refers to a com.jgraph.layout.graph class

Comment: 1 of the JPanel constructors take a LayoutManager argument (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) or you can use the setLayout(LayoutManager mgr) method.

Comment: If you have only 1 graph then use only 1 JPanel. then your error lies in the conversion of your graph